# Data table subtract within data table

Tags: r, data.table

trying to select a value from the data table x and make subtraction within the data table x. 
Example:

```
x <- data.table(CountryName = c("Lithuania", "Lithuania", "Latvia", "Latvia", "Estonia", "Estonia"),
            Year = c(2000, 2001, 2000, 2001, 2000, 2001),
            pop = c(3512, 3486, 2381, 2353, 1401, 1392),
            under1 = c(100, 150, 95, 98, 75, 65), 
            under2 = c(95, 135, 85, 89, 71, 62))
tmp <- data.table(CountryName = "Lithuania", Year = 2000, use.to.adjust = "under1")
setkey(x, CountryName, Year)
```

I'm trying with **tmp** table decide which columns use for subtraction and return just single numeric value.

None of my solutions working. Also, I don't want to create additional values, save them and then subtract.
My tries:

```
x[tmp[, .(CountryName, Year)], pop - tmp$use.to.adjust, with = F ]
Error in eval(jsub, parent.frame(), parent.frame()) : 
 object 'pop' not found

x[tmp[, .(CountryName, Year)], pop - tmp$use.to.adjust ]
Error in pop - tmp$use.to.adjust : 
 non-numeric argument to binary operator

x[tmp[, .(CountryName, Year)], "pop" - tmp$use.to.adjust, with = F ]
 CountryName Year under1 under2
1:   Lithuania 2000    100     9
```

Last example just remove pop column from data table.

want to get:

```
value <- 3512 - 100
```

Thanks for help guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the following would work:

```
x[tmp[, .(CountryName, Year)], pop - .SD, .SDcols = tmp$use.to.adjust]
```

Comment: Thanks, this working as I wanted. Tried ".SD" before, but got confused with using different type input in j sector. 

Thanks again :). Have a good day

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly you want to filter your `data.table` to select the entry which is `'Lithuania'` as country and `2000` as year. A solution for the subtraction you ask could be the following.

```
> my_filter <- x$CountryName == 'Lithuania' & x$Year == 2000
> x[my_filter]$pop - x[my_filter]$under1 
[1] 3412
```

Comment: You understood correctly, but the main idea was that I wanted to subtract inside data table without creating additional vectors.
Thanks for answer :).

Comment: No problem! if you want you can avoid the my_filter step by directly inserting the filter like: `x[x$CountryName == 'Lithuania' & x$Year == 2000]$pop - x[x$CountryName == 'Lithuania' & x$Year == 2000]$under1 `. The difference is only that here you have to type twice the filter specifics ;).